# use streaming api to call method

Tags: java

I have a Paged object which I would like to filter using streaming API:

```
@Component
public class ReturnAssembler {  // code used to convert full object into return dto

    public ReturnResource fromAccount(Return return) {
        ....
        return ...;
    }
}
```

I want to use this code:

```
private ReturnAssembler returnAssembler;

return usersRepository.findAll(spec, pageable).map(returnAssembler.fromAccount(??????));
```

How I can map the result from `findAll` using stream by using `returnAssembler.fromAccount`?

```
@Component
public class ReturnAssembler {  // code used to convert full object into return dto

    public ReturnResource fromAccount(Return return) {
        ....
        return ...;
    }
}


private ReturnAssembler returnAssembler;

return usersRepository.findAll(spec, pageable).map(returnAssembler.fromAccount(??????));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return usersRepository.findAll(spec, pageable).stream()
//assuming usersRepository.findAll returns Collection<T>
.map(user -> returnAssembler.fromAccount(user)
//assuming returnAssembler.fromAccount accepts T as parameter
.tolist(); //.collect(Collectors.toList()); if java version < 17
```

note that usersRepository.findAll return type and returnAssembler.fromAccount parameter type should be the same for this to work, or else you will need an intermediate map operation to make returned type into something returnAssembler.fromAccount accepts as parameter.

Comment: Thanks but I see one issue: `Required type: Page<UsersResource> Provided: List
<UsersResource>` Is there any way to use stream but to preserve return Page object?

Comment: `findAll` returns `Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);`

Comment: page has its own map method so you could just do : usersRepository.findAll(spec, pageable).map(user -> returnAssembler.fromAccount(user)) ; and it will return a new page with the elements mapped as specified.